# Nutch Fetch Scheduler to recrawl web

Tags: nutch

I've followed this [article](http://pascaldimassimo.com/2010/06/11/how-to-re-crawl-with-nutch/) to configure Fetch Schedule for recrawling a website but it doesn't seem to work.
Added the following property in nutch-site.xml to schedule recrawling every 10 minutes as I want to recrawl a particular website to get the changed pages.-

```
<property>
  <name>db.fetch.schedule.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.nutch.crawl.DefaultFetchSchedule</value>
  <description>The implementation of fetch schedule. DefaultFetchSchedule simply 
  adds the original fetchInterval to the last fetch time, regardless of 
  page changes.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>db.fetch.interval.default</name>
  <value>600</value>
  <description>The default number of seconds between re-fetches of a page (30 days). 
  </description>
</property>
```

My question is will recrawling start automatically after every 10 minutes or do I need to do any other configuration or do I have to trigger it somehow?

Comment: Be careful, if you set this too low you may end up with an infinite crawl. If it takes more than 10 minutes to perform the entire crawl, then before it reaches the end this page would be added to the queue again to be re-crawled (I believe, I'm still reasonably new at this myself, but I just read that in an article).

Comment: Yeah I also read the same. But it is of no use as the above configuration doesn't seem to work for me. Whether I set interval to be 5 minutes or 50 minutes, it always starts fresh crawl i.e. it seems that db.fetch.interval.default is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create cronjob to automatically crawling.
db.fetch.interval.default only tells nutch whether this page should be crawled after last crawled.

Comment: So if I set cronjob daily, say at 10:00 am, and set value of db.fetch.interval.default equal to 1 week then no recrawling will actually happen?